# Codeigniter: Will using $this->load->database() multiple times result in multiple connections?

Tags: php, database, performance, codeigniter, connection

I was thinking about removing the database library from my autoload file. I am caching everything on the page so I do not need to connect to the db every time and I figured it is a waste of speed if I have CI connect to the db anyway.

My Question is now: if I for e.g. load the database in MY_Model `$this->load->database()` without parameters (they come from the config file), will a new connection be established for every model I use in a controller?

Or will it be like helpers that are only loaded once?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They only get loaded once. The database class makes  sure of that for you.

Comment: Awesome, that's what I wanted to hear. Is that documented anywhere?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for that now.

Comment: Check line `329` in `system/core/Loader.php`. More details in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

No, You only will connect to one database. The one you specified in `database.php`

You could however connect to multiple databases.
Say you have two connections in `database.php` like the following:

```
/* FORUM */
$active_group = "forum";
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['forum']['hostname'] = "xxxxx";
$db['forum']['username'] = "xxxxx";
$db['forum']['password'] = "xxxxx";
$db['forum']['database'] = "xxxxx";
$db['forum']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$db['forum']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['forum']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['forum']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['forum']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['forum']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['forum']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['forum']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";

/* TEST SITE */
$active_group = "default";
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = "xxxxx";
$db['default']['username'] = "xxxxx";
$db['default']['password'] = "xxxxx";
$db['default']['database'] = "xxxxx";
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
```

You can call this databases using:

```
$this->db_forum = $this->CI->load->database('forum', TRUE);
```

Acces db1 like `$this->db`

And db2 like `$this->db_forum`

You can look at the CI docs for more information: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html

I just used a simple example.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am connecting with same way, but for db2 $this->db_forum is giving error in other Models, do I need to connect to the database db2 in all my models?

Answer (score 1):

Upon loading a model, you can use this:

```
$this->load->model('my_model', NULL, TRUE);
```

The third argument will connect to the database by itself.

Found this by looking into the `system/core/Loader.php`.

And in the same file, `$this->load->database();` is run and returns `FALSE` before connection if `$this->db` is already set, so no worries about multiple connects:

```
// Do we even need to load the database class?
if (class_exists('CI_DB') AND $return == FALSE AND $active_record == NULL AND isset($CI->db) AND is_object($CI->db))
{
    return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working very easy, I have a site which choses a database based on the login username, so I have a "main" database that contains the information of the dynamic selectable database. the way I did is place this code where I need to change the database as follows:

```
$db1['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db1['username'] = $fila['dbusername'];
$db1['password'] = $fila['dbpass'];
$db1['database'] = $fila['dbname'];
$db1['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$db1['dbprefix'] = 'ospos_';
$db1['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db1['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db1['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db1['cachedir'] = '';
$db1['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db1['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db1['swap_pre'] = '';
$db1['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db1['stricton'] = FALSE;

$this->db->close();
$this->load->database($db1,FALSE);
```

If you want to make it permanent once the DB is selected I suggest to use a session var and modify the autoload.php file something like:

```
class DatabaseLoader {
     public function __construct() {
             $this->load();
     }
     public function load() {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $may_db=$CI->session->userdata('may_db');
        if($may_db)
        {
            $CI->db = $CI->load->database($may_db, TRUE);
        }
        else
        {
            $CI->db = $CI->load->database('default', TRUE);
        } 
     }
}
```

And add the the db info to a session var in the first section of code:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('may_db',$db1);
```